# Vectorizing rows/columns of a Matrix in R

Tags: r, variables, matrix, vector

I want to be able to take a matrix in R, and have each row be it's own vector (ideally with a name I can iterate and assign while I loop through the matrix). For example, if I have a matrix, M:

```
> M<-matrix(c(1,-4,-4,3,4,-4,17,15,-12),3,3)
> M
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    3   17
[2,]   -4    4   15
[3,]   -4   -4  -12
```

I would like to be able to go through M and create vectors that I could name so that I end up with each row as it's own, standalone vector:

```
> row1<-M[1,];row2<-M[2,];row3<-M[3,];
> row1
[1]  1  3 17
> row2
[1] -4  4 15
> row3
[1]  -4  -4 -12
```

Clearly I can do this going through, but it'd be a nightmare for a matrix with 100+ rows, and I don't know how to iterate a for loop to allow me to do this where the variable name assignment changes on each iterand. Ideally I'd like to be able to do it where I have a matrix with row names, and then I can assign each vector the variable name that is the rowname of it's row in the original matrix.

Comment: Why would want to do so? Normally, it's easier to have all data in one large structure than to deal with individullay named rows.

Comment: It's for basketball datasets, so I want the ability to look at certain groupings of individuals and I thought it'd be easier to do this with each stored as a named variable rather than referencing rows of the matrix. Maybe I'm mistaken, haven't tried working with the new method yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *can* do this with `assign()`:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(M)) {
    vname <- paste0("row",i)
    assign(vname,row[i,])
}
```

or

```
for (i in rownames(M)) assign(i,M[i,])
```

... but you should think carefully about why you want to. If you do this you're going to end up with a namespace cluttered with individual variables.  Furthermore, to access the individual variables in a loop you're then going to have to jump through ugly and inefficient hoops with `get()` (the inverse of `assign()`).  What's your use case?

Comment: Why even show this? Can't test right now but I think they should use split.

Comment: Maybe you're right.  We can't really tell what the OP wants to do anyway. `apply(M,MARGIN=1,...)` might be the best approach, or `split(M,row(M))`, or ...

Comment: `fortunes::fortune(236)`: _The only people who should use the assign function are those who fully understand why you
should never use the assign function._ :-)

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, thank you! And to answer your question, it's for basketball datasets and so I would want each player individually to look at possibilities of trades and whatnot to be able to construct groupings from the individuals. Maybe that would be best done with just using the appropriate rows of the original dataset, but I wanted to try this method. Follow up: is there a way to make the variable names the rownames of the original matrix?

Comment: that's my second example.  Again, if you gave a more detailed description of your workflow (perhaps as a new question) people might give you some suggestions about more idiomatic/efficient ways to get where you want to go ...